# Google chrome drops FPS for css animation

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-animations

So the problem is only on Google chrome (Version tried - 76.0.3809.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)). I am trying to bring marquee animation for texts. It works well when animation starts, but after about a min it goes blank in the screen, but runs behind. It continues to display after any mouse action.
Tried profiling and found that FPS goes down from 60 to 15 and runs idle. please find the attached profiling screenshot.

[image]

Attaching sandbox link here. https://codesandbox.io/s/static-dvcor (demo: https://dvcor.csb.app/)